# Hide content html

Tags: html

I'd like to hide an specific class from this code, exactly `<div class="default-tab-info">`

```
<header></header>
<section id="home-sidebar" class="header-left admin-bar-showing">
    <div id="side-navigation" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <ul class="tab-nav ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
                <a id="ui-id-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#tab-1" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="icon-home"></span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" role="tabpanel" style="display: block;" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
            <div class="default-tab-info">
                <span class="icon-home"></span>
                <div class="default-tab-inner"
```

I write

```
body.home #icon-home {
    display: none;
}
```

but it doesn't work

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSS should say the following.

```
div.default-tab-info {
    display: none;
}
```

This hides the `div` with the class `default-tab-info`.

---

To hide the icon contained in the `span` element with the `icon-home` class use the following.

```
span.icon-home {
    display: none;
}
```

Also, to hide the `span.icon-home` within the `div.default-tab-info`, the following should do the job.

```
div.default-tab-info span.icon-home {
    display: none;
}
```

This will hide any `span.icon-home` that is the wathever n-th child of `div.default-tab-info`.

Comment: Ok, but this hides all tab info. I'm looking for just to hide home icon...  <span class="icon-home"></span>
Rgds

Comment: Please have a look at my edited answer, it should do what you need it to do.

Comment: Hi, there it is ;) that hides only icon. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `#` character indicates an **id selector** not a **class selector** which uses `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
.default-tab-info{
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j4cT/4/)

Comment: This hides all inside tab-info too

Comment: You need to hide the div class but not its contents?

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed, hide the span inside the div. Michaël van de Weerd gave me the answer. Thanks for your help anyway ;)